# Closing browser window when php is in execution

Tags: php, execution

what exactly is happening when PHP is putting contents (1 MB for example) in a file and the user closes the tab?
Could the file be corrupted? How can I avoid that?
Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcB I have already read it. What I want to know is: if I don't use that function, does PHP execution abort during a single instruction or it waits for the end of the instruction?

Comment: RTM again: [ignore_user_abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and see the notes section where it says _PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client._ So, writing a 1MB file _in one go should be_ safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a client-side issue...

I solved this problem using Javascript's **window.onbeforeunload** and **window.onunload** functions:

```
<head>
<script>
var invalid_exit=0;
var submitted=0;

window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
    if (invalid_exit==1  && submitted==0 ){
        return 'You will lose your progress!';
    }
}

window.onunload = function(){ 
    if (invalid_exit==1  && submitted==0 ){
    //ajax call when an invalid exit is happening...        
    }
</script>
</head>
```

In this case, I used to control variables: invalid_exit and submitted....

You can check if a user clicks a submit button(submitted=1), closes the browser(invalid_exit=0), refreshes the page(invalid_exit=0), etc... Depending on your requirement....

With Jquery you can control every event...

I hope this can help you out!!!